# SQL Server output as XML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

SQL Server code which generates output as XML I am having problem with this that not getting output as per requirement

```sql
select  Section.Text,
        Section.ImageUrl,
        (select Item.Text "Item/@Text",
                Item.Url "Item/@Url",
                Item.ImageUrl "Item/@ImageUrl" 
                for xml path(''),type) as Items

from   tblATNOT_MenuSections Section
join   (select  mit.Text,
                mit.Url,
                mit.ImageUrl,
                mit.Section,
                mit.ItemOrder
        from    tblATNOT_MenuItems mit
        join    tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess rma on (rma.Item = mit.Item and rma.Valid = 1)
        where   (mit.Valid = 1 or mit.Valid is null)
        and rma.Role in (select distinct rum.RoleId
                         from   tblSSAppsRoleUserMap rum
                         join   viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem on (vem.PersonId = rum.PersonId)
                         where  vem.IsEmployeeActive = 'Y' 
                         and    vem.PersonId = 86
                         and    rum.RoleId = rma.Role)
                         or     rma.Role is null    

          )Item 
on (Item.Section = Section.Section)
order by Section.SectionOrder, 
         Item.ItemOrder
for xml auto, root('Menu')
```

Current output:

```
<Menu>
  <Section Text="Home" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/home.gif">
    <Items>
      <Item Text="Home" Url="/ATNOT/Pages/Home.aspx" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </Items>
  </Section>
  <Section Text="Entry" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_go.png">
    <Items>
      <Item Text="Attendance Entry" Url="/ATNOT/Pages/AttendanceEntry.aspx" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </Items>
  </Section>
  <Section Text="Entry" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_go.png">
    <Items>
      <Item Text="My Attendance Requests" Url="/ATNOT/Pages/AttendanceRequests.aspx" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </Items>
  </Section>
  <Section Text="Claim" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/new_tour.gif">
    <Items>
      <Item Text="Back Date OT Claim" Url="/ATNOT/Pages/BackDateClaim.aspx" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </Items>
  </Section>
  <Section Text="Claim" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/new_tour.gif">
    <Items>
      <Item Text="Overtime Claim" Url="/ATNOT/Pages/OvertimeClaim.aspx" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </Items>
  </Section>
  <Section Text="Claim" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/new_tour.gif">
    <Items>
      <Item Text="My Overtime Requests" Url="/ATNOT/Pages/OvertimeRequests.aspx" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </Items>
  </Section>
</Menu>
```

but my requirements as follows..... please tell me what is remaining..

Here child node items getting repeated each time

Desired output:

```
<menu>
  <section text="Home" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/home.gif">
    <items>
      <item text="Home" url="/ATNOT/Pages/Home.aspx" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </items>
  </section>
  <section text="Entry" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_go.png">
    <items>
      <item text="Attendance Entry" url="/ATNOT/Pages/AttendanceEntry.aspx" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
      <item text="My Attendance Requests" url="/ATNOT/Pages/AttendanceRequests.aspx" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </items>
  </section>
  <section text="Claim" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/new_tour.gif">
    <items>
      <item text="Back Date OT Claim" url="/ATNOT/Pages/BackDateClaim.aspx" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
      <item text="Overtime Claim" url="/ATNOT/Pages/OvertimeClaim.aspx" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
      <item text="My Overtime Requests" url="/ATNOT/Pages/OvertimeRequests.aspx" image_url="/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png" />
    </items>
  </section>
</menu>
```

DDL script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSSAppsRoleUserMap]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProfitCenterCode] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [CostCenterCode] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [LocationCode] [int] NULL,
    [OrgEntityCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Active] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_rum_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
               ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblSSAppsRoleUserMap] ON
INSERT [dbo].[tblSSAppsRoleUserMap] ([Id], [RoleId], [PersonId], [ProfitCenterCode], [CostCenterCode], [LocationCode], [OrgEntityCode], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (1, 1, 37306, N'100', N'100', 100, N'3736', 1, 38331, CAST(0x0000A307012DD394 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[tblSSAppsRoleUserMap] ([Id], [RoleId], [PersonId], [ProfitCenterCode], [CostCenterCode], [LocationCode], [OrgEntityCode], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (2, 1, 38440, N'100', N'100', 100, N'3482', 1, 36540, CAST(0x0000A2AE01043994 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[tblSSAppsRoleUserMap] ([Id], [RoleId], [PersonId], [ProfitCenterCode], [CostCenterCode], [LocationCode], [OrgEntityCode], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (2797, 184, 194, N'100', N'100', 100, NULL, 1, 1, CAST(0x0000A3F000BED520 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[tblSSAppsRoleUserMap] ([Id], [RoleId], [PersonId], [ProfitCenterCode], [CostCenterCode], [LocationCode], [OrgEntityCode], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn]) VALUES (2798, 184, 449, N'100', N'100', 100, NULL, 1, 1, CAST(0x0000A3F000BED520 AS DateTime))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblSSAppsRoleUserMap] OFF

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuSections]
(
    [Section] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Text] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Url] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [ImageUrl] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [SectionOrder] [int] NULL,
    [Valid] [bit] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_mes_Section] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Section] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  
              ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuSections] ([Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [SectionOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (1, N'Home', NULL, N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/home.gif', 1, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuSections] ([Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [SectionOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (2, N'Entry', NULL, N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_go.png', 2, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuSections] ([Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [SectionOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (3, N'Claim', NULL, N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/new_tour.gif', 3, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuSections] ([Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [SectionOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (4, N'Report', NULL, N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/reportExcel.gif', 4, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuSections] ([Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [SectionOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (5, N'Administrator', NULL, N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/admin1.png', 5, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems]    Script Date: 12/16/2014 14:43:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems](
    [Item] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Section] [int] NULL,
    [Text] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Url] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [ImageUrl] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [ItemOrder] [int] NULL,
    [Valid] [bit] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_meit_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Item] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (1, 1, N'Home', N'/ATNOT/Pages/Home.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 1, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (2, 2, N'Attendance Entry', N'/ATNOT/Pages/AttendanceEntry.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 1, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (3, 2, N'My Attendance Requests', N'/ATNOT/Pages/AttendanceRequests.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 2, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (4, 3, N'Overtime Claim', N'/ATNOT/Pages/OvertimeClaim.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 2, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3FC011E85EA AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (5, 3, N'Back Date OT Claim', N'/ATNOT/Pages/BackDateClaim.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 1, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (6, 3, N'My Overtime Requests', N'/ATNOT/Pages/OvertimeRequests.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 3, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (7, 4, N'Daily Overtime ', N'/ATNOT/Reports/DailyOvertimeReport.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 1, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (8, 4, N'Monthly Overtime ', N'/ATNOT/Reports/MonthlyOvertimeReport.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 2, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (9, 4, N'Monthly Shift Allowance ', N'/ATNOT/Reports/MonthlyShiftAllowanceReport.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 3, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (10, 4, N'Detailed Overtime Report', N'/ATNOT/Reports/DetailedOvertimeReport.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 4, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item], [Section], [Text], [Url], [ImageUrl], [ItemOrder], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (11, 5, N'Back Date Entry', N'/ATNOT/Admin/BackDateEntry.aspx', N'/ATNOT/Include/Images/page_add.png', 1, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3A400000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess]    Script Date: 12/16/2014 14:43:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Role] [int] NULL,
    [Item] [int] NULL,
    [Valid] [bit] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_rma_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ON
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (1, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (2, NULL, 2, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (3, NULL, 3, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (4, NULL, 4, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (5, NULL, 5, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (6, NULL, 6, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (7, 161, 7, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (8, 161, 8, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (9, 161, 9, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (10, 161, 10, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ([Id], [Role], [Item], [Valid], [Active], [CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedOn]) VALUES (11, 172, 11, 1, 1, 3591, CAST(0x0000A3C200000000 AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] OFF
/****** Object:  Default [DF__tblATNOT___Valid__7F16D496]    Script Date: 12/16/2014 14:43:27 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Valid]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF__tblATNOT___Activ__000AF8CF]    Script Date: 12/16/2014 14:43:27 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [fk_mit_mse_Section_Section]    Script Date: 12/16/2014 14:43:27 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_mit_mse_Section_Section] FOREIGN KEY([Section])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuSections] ([Section])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_mit_mse_Section_Section]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [fk_rac_mit_Item_Item]    Script Date: 12/16/2014 14:43:27 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_rac_mit_Item_Item] FOREIGN KEY([Item])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblATNOT_MenuItems] ([Item])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_rac_mit_Item_Item]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [fk_rac_rma_Role_RoleId]    Script Date: 12/16/2014 14:43:27 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_rac_rma_Role_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([Role])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblSSAppsRoleMaster] ([RoleId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_rac_rma_Role_RoleId]
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that giving desired Output :

```
select Section.Text,
       Section.ImageUrl,
       (
         select Item.Text "Item/@Text",
                Item.Url "Item/@Url",
                Item.ImageUrl "Item/@ImageUrl" 
         from tblATNOT_MenuItems as Item
         inner join tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess as rma on Item.Item = rma.Item and rma.Valid = 1
         where  Section.Section = Item.Section 
                and (Item.Valid = 1 or Item.Valid is null) 
                and (rma.Role in (select distinct rum.RoleId
                                  from   tblSSAppsRoleUserMap rum
                                  join   viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem on (vem.PersonId = rum.PersonId)
                                  where  vem.IsEmployeeActive = 'Y' 
                                         and vem.PersonId = @p_PersonId
                                         and rum.RoleId = rma.Role)
                or rma.Role is null)

         order by Item.ItemOrder
         for xml path(''), type
       ) as Items

from tblATNOT_MenuSections as Section
where exists (
                 select *
                 from tblATNOT_MenuItems as Item
                 inner join tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess as rma on Item.Item = rma.Item and rma.Valid = 1
                 where  Section.Section = Item.Section 
                        and (Item.Valid = 1 or Item.Valid is null) 
                        and (rma.Role in (select distinct rum.RoleId
                                          from   tblSSAppsRoleUserMap rum
                                          join   viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem on (vem.PersonId = rum.PersonId)
                                          where  vem.IsEmployeeActive = 'Y' 
                                                 and vem.PersonId = @p_PersonId
                                                 and rum.RoleId = rma.Role)
                        or rma.Role is null)
             )
order by Section.SectionOrder
for xml auto, root('Menu')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your query to use `for xml path` and use the query to get items in a correlated subquery in the column list.

Here is a simplified example to show what I mean.

```sql
select S.Text,
       S.ImageUrl,
       (
         select I.Text as '@Text',
                I.Url as '@Url',
                I.ImageUrl as '@ImageUrl'
         from Item as I -- Replace with your Items query
         where S.Section = I.Section -- The correlation to Section
         order by I.ItemOrder
         for xml path('Item'), type
       ) as Items
from tblATNOT_MenuSections as S
order by S.SectionOrder
for xml path('section'), root('Menu')
```

Using your tables except `viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended`

```sql
select S.Text,
       S.ImageUrl,
       (
         select I.Text as '@Text',
                I.Url as '@Url',
                I.ImageUrl as '@ImageUrl'
         from tblATNOT_MenuItems as I
           inner join tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess as R
             on I.Item = R.Item and 
                R.Valid = 1
         where S.Section = I.Section and
               (I.Valid = 1 or I.Valid is null) and
               (R.Role in (
                          select M.RoleId
                          from tblSSAppsRoleUserMap M
                          ) or R.Role is null)
         order by I.ItemOrder
         for xml path('Item'), type
       ) as Items
from tblATNOT_MenuSections as S
order by S.SectionOrder
for xml path('section'), root('Menu')
```

To filter on rows that has no match in the subquery you have to duplicate the logic in an exists clause in the main query.

```sql
select S.Text,
       S.ImageUrl,
       (
         select I.Text as '@Text',
                I.Url as '@Url',
                I.ImageUrl as '@ImageUrl'
         from tblATNOT_MenuItems as I
           inner join tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess as R
             on I.Item = R.Item and 
                R.Valid = 1
         where S.Section = I.Section and 
               (I.Valid = 1 or I.Valid is null) and
               (R.Role in (
                          select M.RoleId
                          from tblSSAppsRoleUserMap M
                          ) or R.Role is null)
         order by I.ItemOrder
         for xml path('Item'), type
       ) as Items
from tblATNOT_MenuSections as S
where exists (
             select *
             from tblATNOT_MenuItems as I
               inner join tblATNOT_RoleMenuAccess as R
                 on I.Item = R.Item and 
                    R.Valid = 1
             where S.Section = I.Section and 
                  (I.Valid = 1 or I.Valid is null) and
                  (R.Role in (
                             select M.RoleId
                             from tblSSAppsRoleUserMap M
                             ) or R.Role is null)
             )
order by S.SectionOrder
for xml path('section'), root('Menu')
```

Comment: this code is not working means i am not getting output as per requirement cause there is JOIN then how to implement your code into my code

Comment: @taj Add the DDL (code to create tables) for the tables you are using to the question and I will have a look at it.

Comment: @taj You forgot viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended. Added a version without that table. Perhaps you can add that one in yourself?

Comment: this is working only instead of                                  for xml path('section'), root('Menu')                              i took for xml auto, root('Menu')

Comment: @taj Why? That will not give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: one problem is there i e getting some extra records from table S,  actually there is JOIN between tblATNOT_MenuSections  and subquery Items then how to implement join or there is some other way to get desired output

Comment: @taj This is the join you are looking for `where S.Section = I.Section and`. The join between `tblATNOT_MenuSections` and `tblATNOT_MenuItems`. It is in the where clause of the correlated subquery.

Comment: actually join between tblATNOT_MenuSections and Item taken as a subquery just as above in question i asked ...

Comment: @taj Yes, and that is done in the where clause in the subquery as I said.

Comment: but here i am getting two section text extra .. that i don't want,  means some records from tblATNOT_MenuSections is coming which do not have related records from tblATNOT_MenuItems........ <Section Text="Report" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/reportExcel.gif" />
  <Section Text="Administrator" ImageUrl="/ATNOT/Include/Images/admin1.png" />

Comment: let me check with that